# números primos de 0 a 10 em mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde, estou tendo dificuldade nesta pergunta de MySQL:

**Mostre o nome dos animais e o codigo da raça. Apenas mostre os animais que contenham em seu respectivo código um numero primo de 0 até 10.**

Tentei com o seguinte código:

```
SELECT nome, raca from animais where 
(codigo > 0 and codigo < 10)
and (codigo % 1 = 0 and codigo % 2 = 0) or (codigo % 1 = 0 and codigo % 3 = 0) or 
(codigo % 1 = 0 and codigo % 5 = 0) or (codigo % 1 = 0 and codigo % 7 = 0)
```

Dá o seguinte erro, apenas:

**Erro = { Resposta com Erro }**

Pois estou resolvendo questões do sqlweb.com.br. A seguir a imagem do site com a pergunta, a resposta e o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite a pergunta com o erro gerado.

Comment: **Dica**: sua verificação pode ser simplificada para `codigo in (2, 3, 5, 7)`, pois você sabe que são esses os números primos entre 0 e 10 - e isso não mudará tão cedo.

Comment: O "contenham" do enunciado é ambíguo. Valem códigos que tenham um *dígito* primo?

Comment: @bfavaretto eu entendi que vale qualquer código que possua um dígito primo, tal como 34 entrar, visto que o 3 é primo. Mas está bem confuso.

Comment: codigo in (2, 3, 5, 7) tb dá erro

Comment: Qualquer número é divisível por 1 e portanto  o resto da divisão de qualquer inteiro por 1 sempre será zero.

Answer (score -1):

Como os número primos entre 0 e 10 são poucos e é uma regra da matemática, ou seja, algo exato, podemos utilizar o código fixo para verificar se o número é primo:

Número primos entre 0 e 10: **2, 3, 5, 7**

```
SELECT nome, raca 
  FROM animais 
 WHERE codigo in (2, 3, 5, 7)
```

Comment: @João Ricardo, isso deve resolver

Comment: Não, continua dando erro..estou desconfiado ou que é erro do próprio site, ou que não entendi exatamente a pergunta..na dúvida pulei a pergunta